# Expanding a tree with radio buttons

Tags: navigation, controls, checkboxes, radio-buttons, tree

I have tree. Each tree node is a radio button. Nodes can be expanded/collapsed by clicking the disclosure icon which is a grey triangle. Some radio buttons are disabled.

If a radio button is disabled, should clicking it expand/collapse the node. In other words, should it act as a secondary toggle button?

I'm considering this because the user wouldn't have to move the pointer over the disclosure icon to toggle the node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Each control should have its own separate interaction role**. It will be clear and familiar for a user.

Assigning "tricky" behavior makes interaction unclear, because rules are hidden from user. Clear and familiar interaction, which is aligned with user expectations, based on previous experience:
a) reduces errors,
b) makes learning curve low,
c) increaces efficiency and effectivenes.
In other words, brings good UX.

Also don't forget to set item labels to check radios.